# Isolate nested div with :active pseudo selector

Tags: html, css, nested, pseudo-class

The problem I'm working with has nested divs where their active states should be isolated from each other. For example, if the child is clicked, it should not change the active state of the parent.

In the case of the below example, only the orange/red square should be selected, but as you can see triggering it also triggers its parent.

[image: nested divs]

I've written some JavaScript to fix this problem by isolating the event target, but I would like to find a CSS solution for this if it exists.

HTML:

```
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.outer:active {
  background-color: purple;
}

.inner:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```